# Robo3t application not starting up from gui as well as terminal in Ubuntu 22

Tags: ubuntu-22.04, robo3t

I've upgraded my system from `Ubuntu 20.04.5` to `Ubuntu 22.04.2`. After the upgradation, it's failing to start/open `robo3T` application. I tried opening it from GUI as well as the terminal. I don't get any error when I try to open it from GUI, While I get an error when try it open it from the terminal.

```
`This application failed to start because it could not find or load the Qt platform plugin "wayland-egl"
in "".
Available platform plugins are: eglfs, linuxfb, minimal, minimalegl, offscreen, vnc, xcb, xcb.
Reinstalling the application may fix this problem`
```

It would be great if you can help me out with this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The workaround hack wayland disabling worked for me as,

`DISABLE_WAYLAND=1 robo3t-snap`

I started my robo3T by using this command on the terminal.